# How to get DataFrame.pct_change to calculate monthly change on daily price data?

Tags: python, pandas

I know that it is possible to offset with the `periods` argument, but how would one go about return-izing daily price data that is spread throughout a month (trading days, for example)?

Example data is:

```
In [1]: df.AAPL
2009-01-02 16:00:00    90.36
2009-01-05 16:00:00    94.18
2009-01-06 16:00:00    92.62
2009-01-07 16:00:00    90.62
2009-01-08 16:00:00    92.30
2009-01-09 16:00:00    90.19
2009-01-12 16:00:00    88.28
2009-01-13 16:00:00    87.34
2009-01-14 16:00:00    84.97
2009-01-15 16:00:00    83.02
2009-01-16 16:00:00    81.98
2009-01-20 16:00:00    77.87
2009-01-21 16:00:00    82.48
2009-01-22 16:00:00    87.98
2009-01-23 16:00:00    87.98
...
2009-12-10 16:00:00    195.59
2009-12-11 16:00:00    193.84
2009-12-14 16:00:00    196.14
2009-12-15 16:00:00    193.34
2009-12-16 16:00:00    194.20
2009-12-17 16:00:00    191.04
2009-12-18 16:00:00    194.59
2009-12-21 16:00:00    197.38
2009-12-22 16:00:00    199.50
2009-12-23 16:00:00    201.24
2009-12-24 16:00:00    208.15
2009-12-28 16:00:00    210.71
2009-12-29 16:00:00    208.21
2009-12-30 16:00:00    210.74
2009-12-31 16:00:00    209.83
Name: AAPL, Length: 252
```

As you can see, simply offsetting by 30 would not produce correct results, as there are gaps in the timestamp data, not every month is 30 days, etc.  I know there must be an easy way to do this using pandas.

Comment: the difference is due to to the different frequency: `BM` is business month, while `M` is month (see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can resample the data to business month. If you don't want the mean price (which is the default in `resample`) you can use a custom resample method using the keyword argument `how`:

```
In [31]: from pandas.io import data as web

# read some example data, note that this is not exactly your data!
In [32]: s = web.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start='2009-01-02',
...                             end='2009-12-31')['Adj Close']

# resample to business month and return the last value in the period
In [34]: monthly = s.resample('BM', how=lambda x: x[-1])

In [35]: monthly
Out[35]: 
Date
2009-01-30     89.34
2009-02-27     88.52
2009-03-31    104.19
...
2009-10-30    186.84
2009-11-30    198.15
2009-12-31    208.88
Freq: BM

In [36]: monthly.pct_change()
Out[36]: 
Date
2009-01-30         NaN
2009-02-27   -0.009178
2009-03-31    0.177022
...
2009-10-30    0.016982
2009-11-30    0.060533
2009-12-31    0.054151
Freq: BM
```

Comment: note you can also use `asfreq('M', fill_method='ffill')`. Some care will need to be taken with the intraday data however

Comment: @WesMcKinney Don't know which method is preferred: normally I would use `resample`. Are there any advantages when using `asfreq`? (when using `asfreq` the keyword seems to be `method` (not `fill_method` in 0.10)

Comment: Please see **Update** in Question.

Comment: I added a comment to your question. `resample` should work, not sure about advantages of `asfreq`.

Comment: Thanks.  Removed Update and flagged answered.

Comment: resample has a new syntax: `__main__:1: FutureWarning: how in .resample() is deprecated the new syntax is .resample(...)..apply(<func>)`. So this call will become `In [34]: monthly = s.resample('BM').apply(lambda x: x[-1])`

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on this error as well while using the pct_change function, and would like to offer my two cents on this question.

The freq argument for the pct_change function seems to only accept fixed-period time offset, such as "2D" and "3D". However, "M" is an indefinite time period, and could range between 28 day to 31 day. So that's where the errors come from.

Pct_change operates similarly to the rolling() function, and using "M" time offset with rolling() would get the same error.

Here is a working example using the freq argument in the pct_change argument:

import pandas_datareader.data as web

```
return.pct_change(periods = 1, freq = '2D')

Date
2008-03-26         NaN
2008-03-27         NaN
2008-03-28   -0.010342
2008-03-31         NaN
2008-04-01         NaN
            ...
```