# Use pandas to calculate pct_change based on specified freq

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate a stock's trailing month-on-month return, on a daily basis (looking back every ~30 days or so). Ideally, if the data on the previous month's date is not available (no stock stock price over weekend or public holiday), the process should pull the last valid row value available.

With sample data as follows:

```
Date, ABC
2019-10-18,1.00
2019-11-20,1.01
2019-11-22,1.02
2019-12-20,1.03
2019-12-23,1.04
```

and my code being:

```
df.pct_change(freq='M')
```

However, I seem to get only NaN. Does anyone know how best to approach this? The manually computed output i'm looking for should be as follows:

```
NaN
0.01
0.02
0.019802
0.019608
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get DataFrame.pct\_change to calculate monthly change on daily price data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036397/how-to-get-dataframe-pct-change-to-calculate-monthly-change-on-daily-price-data)

Comment: Thanks but I might have an alternative imperfect solution - I have used df.pct_change(periods=20) against my dataframe of 'daily stock prices' as a proxy instead (20 'business' days in a month).